# Как запретить повторение значений в таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
| ID | Login | Post     |
+----+-------+----------+
| 1  | Woddy | manager  |
| 2  | Simi  | operator |
| 3  | Woddy | agent    |
```

Надо ограничение, например чтобы у `Woddy` не было разных `Post`(должностей).
Создал индекс, сделал уникальным поля `Login` и `Post`.
Как понимаю это можно реализовать через Constraints, тогда что писать в `expressions`.
Нужно чтобы `Login` не повторялся
Скрипт индекса:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
 ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Person UNIQUE (Login ,Post)
```

Comment: создаём индекс по полю `Login`, при попытке добавить пользователя `Wooddy` повторно возникнет исключение.

Comment: @ Bald56rus, создал индекс по полю Login, сделал уникальным, но не работает

Comment: Добавьте немного деталей, как Вы создали Index, покажите скрипт создания таблицы, при помощи чего Вы работает с бд.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Созданный вами:

```
CONSTRAINT uc_Person UNIQUE (Login, Post)
```

делает пару `(Login ,Post)` уникальной, т.е. Woddy может быть manager, но такая запись может быть только одна, Woddy не может быть manager дважды, и ему не запрещено иметь другие Post.

Соответственно, чтобы Login не повторялся должно быть:

```
CONSTRAINT uc_Person UNIQUE (Login)
```

Answer (score 2):

пример из первого результата гуглинга по запросу `ms sql unique constraint`

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE TABLE Production.TransactionHistoryArchive4
 (
   TransactionID int NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT AK_TransactionID UNIQUE(TransactionID) 
); 
GO
```

Comment: мне кажется у тс проблема не с кодом а с пониманием

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Name
ON Persons (Name)
GO

INSERT INTO Persons
(Name)
VALUES
('Email'),
('Twitter');
```

Попытаемся вставить дубликат:

```
insert into Persons (Name) Values ('Twitter');
```

Получаем:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Persons' with unique index 'Name'. The duplicate key value is (Twitter).